# Nginx : Get last value of URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am posting here because I have not found an answer to the following problem.

I have the following url: https://www.example.com/archives/5852555.pdf

and I need to keep only 5852555.pdf to pass this value to http://localhost:3001/download.php?file=5852555 .

For now, I have the following configuration:

```
location ~* ^/archives/([0-9]+)\.(txt|rtf|doc|docx|pdf)$ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/download.php?file=$1 ; 
}
```

But $1 is still empty, and I don't understand why.

Can you help me?

P.S. I'm relatively new to nginx, thanks for your understanding.

I'm using nginx 1.23.2 .

Comment: Other than the missing `;` after the `proxy_pass` statement, the configuration fragment in your question works for me. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to test and view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Indeed, it was a typo for the semicolon in my post but not in my server configuration file.

I corrected it on the post and also added the same regular expression from my server.

Now, after restarting my nginx, it does not restart.

I have the following error: 

`nginx:[emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have a URI part in the location given by the regular expression, or inside the named location, or inside the "if" statement, or inside the "limit_except" block`

Can you help me?

Comment: I do not get that error with the configuration you posted. It is behaving as if the `$1` is missing.

Comment: Same here, works fine, no error. Probably you have another proxy_pass block?